# Simultaneous commands

Tags: video, bash, mplayer

I'm trying to get bash to execute two commands simultaneously. I've read a little about job control, &, bg, fg, but the problem is that the command I want to run doesn't run properly in the bg.

Specifically, I'm trying to get two movie files to start running simultaneously in mplayer (to compare the two).

```
$ mplayer [file1] & mplayer [file2] &
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried writing a script that performs that performs this kind of task?

Here is a simple one.

```
#!/bin/bash

mplayer [file1] & 
mplayer [file2] &
```

Comment: ah, this works perfectly. Why is that?

Comment: Ah, I would not like to spoil things for you, so that is all you are getting: **Welcome to the magnificent world of linux!**

Comment: @user80555 On a more serious note, this is a **script**. It is a file that has some **command line interpreter commands**, that your cli parses and executes on the order given. You can do a bazillion of things with scripts. As a matter of fact scripts are all the rage in linux. If you are interested in learning more, look [here](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ch02sec01.html)

Comment: Ah, please use italics as the first option for emphasizing something instead of jumping directly to bold. :) thanks!

Comment: @izx Is bold annoying? If it is I shall stop using it.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: it is distracting, compared to italics, when used to merely emphasize something. Think of bold as almost like "all caps", i.e. when you REALLY want to emphasize something, use it, otherwise use italics. Thanks for all your recent great answers!

Comment: @izx Then I am sorry for overusing it up until this point. In the future, I will use italics. =)

Comment: @NlightNFotis: thanks, also bold is good in answers when you want to make titles for the paragraph below, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that without a script.Run this command:

```
(mplayer [file1] &);mplayer [file2] &
```

Comment: actually, it needs to be

   $(mplayer [file1] &);(mplayer [file2] &)

Comment: **No**,it does not matter if you put the second part inside brackets.